# Udev rule for multi monitor hotplug

Tags: x11, udev, xrandr

I have a laptop connected to a external monitor. I want to configure the display settings automatically when the external monitor is connected or disconnected. So, i understand that this can be accomplished using udev events and a bash script using xrandr.

[This is the bash script](https://pastebin.com/NTE7dkze)

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

VGA_STATUS=$(</sys/class/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1/status)

if [ "connected" == $VGA_STATUS ]; then
    /usr/bin/xrandr --output LVDS1 --noprimary --auto
    /usr/bin/xrandr --output VGA1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --left-of LVDS1
    echo "VGA plugged in" >> /home/my_username/monitor.log
else
    /usr/bin/xrandr --output VGA1 --off
    /usr/bin/xrandr --output LVDS1 --primary --auto
    echo "External monitor disconnected" >> /home/my_username/monitor.log
    exit
fi
```

[This is the udev rule](https://pastebin.com/BjWY94Am)

```
KERNEL=="card0", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority", RUN+="/bin/bash /path/to/my/script.sh"
```

I tested the bash script and it works in both cases. The problem i have is that the udev rule only works when the monitor gets disconnected but not in the other case. The log file shows the "External monitor disconnected" message but it doesn't show the "VGA plugged in" message.

This is the output of `xrandr -q` when i disconnect the external monitor:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1366x768      59.98*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This is the output of `xrandr -q` after the external monitor is connected:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1366x768      59.98*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This is the output of `xrandr -q` after the external monitor is connected and i run the bash script manually:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1366x768      59.98*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

What i'm doing wrong?

i'm in Fedora 25 using i3.

Comment: Why does your script start with `#!/bin/sh` if you run it with `/bin/bash`?

Comment: @Gilles So `ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority"` is not enough?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev You need to set `DISPLAY` as well, and obviously this'll only work if you use gdm, it's already started and user 1000 is logged in. So in particular it won't work if the monitor is plugged in at boot time.

Comment: https://github.com/jceb/srandrd is what you need. It listens for the xorg events opposed to the often too early udev events (That I suspect xorg listens to.)